# SMS ContentObserver failed status not working- Samsung

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I am implementing a ContentObserver for SMS.
I  the `onChange` function I got call when any change in the SMS (Android Default Message application).
I have tested with with LeEco it is working fine, triggered while send,receive,failed, etc.
But, In Samsung Galaxy S6 it is not working for **failed** condition. Others, sent/receive sms is working fine.

```
private static final String CONTENT_SMS = "content://sms";
private static final String MSG_ID = "_id";
private static final String MSG_TYPE = "type";
private static final String MSG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String MSG_DATE = "date";
private static final String MSG_BODY = "body";

String lastMessageID = "";

public final Uri CONTENT_SMS_URI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_SMS);

public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);


        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_SMS_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToNext()){

          //  String protocol = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
            int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MSG_TYPE));

            String newMsgId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MSG_ID));
            if (!lastMessageID.equals(newMsgId)){
                lastMessageID = newMsgId;

                String to = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MSG_ADDRESS));
                Date now = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MSG_DATE)));
                String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MSG_BODY));

                if (type == Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT){
                    // SMS sent
                    Log.e("MSG_SENT", to + " - " + now + " - " + message);

                }
                else if(type == Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.MESSAGE_TYPE_FAILED){
                    // Failed out going message
                    Log.e("MSG_FAILED", to + " - " + now + " - " + message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which Android versions are those devices running?

Comment: @MikeM. Android version 6 (Marshmallow). I tested with LeEco , it is working fine (same OS version).

Comment: Hmm, then the LeEco would seem to be non-standard. Since Marshmallow, the SMS Provider has had a restricted view for non-default apps that allows them to see only the sent and inbox messages.

Comment: @MikeM. But, getting failed response if I send by using SMSManager.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean your `ContentObserver` works if your app sends with `SmsManager`? Or are you talking about the message status from the `PendingIntent` you pass in the `SmsManager#send*()` methods?

Comment: @MikeM. I Could able to get response by using SMSManager. But, When I send from default Message app I won't get any sent//fail response. So, I am trying to implement ContentObserver for catch the default message app sent/fail response.

Comment: Assuming that's a "yes" to my second question, the Provider and `SmsManager` are two separate things. The Provider is just storage for messages. `SmsManager` does provide success/failure status to the sending app, but that's not directly related to the Provider and storing the messages. In fact, the default app uses the status from `SmsManager` to determine in which box to store a message in the Provider. If a message does get sent from the default, then your app can know about it with relative certainty. Otherwise, you're kind of in the dark, at least on those devices with the restricted view

Comment: I assume that , from Marshmallow there is no way to implement failed response of default Message app. Thank you Mike for the prompt support.

Comment: Yeah, not really, not with any kind of certainty, anyway. I'm not sure exactly what your setup is, but if you're trying to keep an eye on a message you're sending from your app via `Intent`, then likely the best you could do to determine a failure is to put some sort of timeout on the Observer. After a certain amount of time, assume it's a failure, and proceed as needed, whether that involves prompting the user, maybe doing a query to see if the user changed the number manually, etc.